# Magento2 Enterprise Search what’s changed?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, search

I am trying to find what Enterprise features we have out of the box in Magento 2. I do apologize for a broad question but it’s really hard to find information about this topic now, so hope community can help, share experience.

What search improvements we have comparing to the first version?
What new functionality and out of the box features available for search result tuning?
Is it easier to customize Enterprise search (add CMS search for example) ?

Answer (score 5):

Checkout out this link for [Enterprise features](https://magento.com/products/enterprise-edition).

For search we've made some significant improvements in 2.0 over M1x.

- Streamlined MySQL Search Engine Config to just FullText Search
- Replaced / Tuned MySQL FullText Search Engine to be more accurate
- Introduced Attribute Weighting for search via attributes configuration
- Introduced query, indexer interface, and layered nav interfaces for easier 3rd party search engine integration

In 2.0 Enterprise Edition ; we've updated our Enterprise search engine to use Solr 4.x

As has been discussed/presented in various webinar's we'll be switching to Elasticsearch in our 2.1 release as our Enterprise search engine.  We'll still support the Solr search adapter but will be building new search features against Elasticsearch.  We believe Elasticsearch provides more opportunities as an element in our Enterprise tech stack to open the doors for future development or our community to extend.  In addition many folks are already using the ELK stack for log management for their site deployments.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I asked my question because I was not able to find something except this general promo info. I used built-in Solr and few custom Elastic Search modules in M1, but don't understand what new features already present in M2, an how I can work with it to expand for my needs.   So I hope to have some experience sharing .

Comment: The big change in M2 is the use of interfaces in search.  Here's an example of how one community member is using the query interface to create an auto-complete/preview extension (https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-SmartSearch).  There's also an indexer interface that can be used to load data to search on (ie like search on CMS or category).  Right now there's not a lot of documentation on our dev docs site for this.  Would be great if you can help us document.  Please add a how to ( http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/bk-how-do-i.html ).   Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot Chuck, it looks like it's what I was asking for